# How to use Jackson PropertyNamingStrategy with Immutables library

Tags: java, jackson, immutability, immutables-library

I am using https://immutables.github.io/ library with Jackson.
I want my class to be Jackson-serializable. I would like to use custom `PropertyNamingStrategy` (configured for `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` using   `mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);`

Unfortunately Immutables library puts `@JsonProperty("propertyName")` at every field in generated code. That overrides PropertyNamingStrategy defined at mapper level (or at class level, using `@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming` annotation).

Is it possible to make Immutables library stop putting property name for every field (using `org.immutables.value.Value.Style` or similar means)?

I have come with workaround, putting @JsonProperty (without value) at every property, but I am not satisfied with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style property `forceJacksonPropertyNames=false` does not force property names to specific strings. It works with naming strategies configured at class level and at mapper level.

Introduction to styles is available here: http://immutables.github.io/style.html

You can read some background information about this setting in issues: https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/431 https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/353

Comment: Thanks! forceJacksonPropertyNames = false indeed has the result that generated Immutable* class has JsonProperty annotations without name. That causes Jackson to respect naming strategy of my com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter, or naming strategy set by @JsonNaming on class level.

It would be great to have forceJacksonPropertyNames documeted on http://immutables.github.io/style.html page. Currently it is not mentioned on that page, and whole org.immutables.value.Value.Style is not docummented in javadoc.

Comment: It's hard to keep documentation page and Javadoc in sync, so they have different roles: the page serves as an introduction to styles, where Javadoc is a detailed (as much as it tries) reference. Sorry if that's less transparent that it should be, we'll try to improve this! Thank you!